# wxPython install PermissionError/Permission denied on Win10/64 machine

Tags: installation, wxpython

trying to install wxPython using pip install -U wxPython.

I get the below error, 
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\program files\python36\Lib\site-packages\six.py'

I've searched everywhere for a solution.  I have changed the Python36 dir security for complete read/write.  At a loss on what to do.

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Geeez, was NOT running Shell as administr.  Installed as admin and everything is working.  Getting Old is not for the meek.

Comment: Yeah, when installing to Program Files in Windows 7 and above, you need to run as administrator. Alternatively you can also install Python to a non-admin location to prevent this issue from happening in the first place.